Where is the NestJS API documentation?
I am looking for API documentation for the core NestJS classes and functions.
Looking at https://docs.nestjs.com/ there's a lot of content but no API documentation as such.
Am I missing something?

There is no API documentation otherwise it would be pretty easy to find. There's a old WIP one here: https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/413
But you can use this unofficial one: https://api-references-nestjs.netlify.app/api
